# Architecture for Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, ssas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am designing an architecture for Power BI.
I am thinking this one on Azure Data Lake Store gen1 :

DSL => Databricks => Snowflakes => Azure Analysis Services (Tabular) => Power BI

- Is this architecture relevant ?
- Does Snownflakes and Analysis Services have the right connectors ?

Thank you

Comment: I would use ADLS Gen 2 now.  Also consider if Power BI Premium can do what you need instead of Azure Analysis Services (AAS).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recommends to use [Modern Data Warehouse Architecture](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/modern-data-warehouse/) to build systems today, so on your first question the answer is yes.

[image]

And the answer to your second question is also yes, Power BI supports both Analysis Services and Snowflake, as you can see in the [list of supported data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources).

Comment: Thank you Andrey.
Yes, this modern DW architecture is my second scenario. But I was thinking that remplacing Azure SQL DW with Snowflakes can be more interesting. 
So, Analysis Services can connect to Snowflakes and answers query from Power BI ? Is that correct ?